# How to add unique values from a variable and "ALL" to the drop down menu in shiny slector

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have used an input (csv) file to populate a dataframe in shiny and what I am planning to do is to create a list of choices which will have all the unique values from a variable and also an option of "ALL" so that by default selected value is ALL, and it will not filter the dataset, but if selected any other value, it will filter the dataset accordingly. Part of code is shown here:

```
data_set <- reactive({
  req(input$file1)
  inFile <- input$file1
  data_set <-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header)
})

observe({
    require(dplyr)
    req(input$file1)    # the dataset is read from CSV file
    choices = c("ALL", unique(as.character(data_set()$variable)))

    updateSelectInput(session,"Var1",
                             label = "Select ID",
                             choices = choices, selected=choices[1])

})

selectInput(inputId = "Var1", label = "Select ID", multiple = FALSE, 
             choices = list("ALL") )


df1 <- reactive({
      if input$Var1 == "ALL" {
        data_set()  
      } else {
        data_set() %>%
          filter(variable == input$Var1)
      }

  })
```

I am not able to include "ALL" choice in the code and I need help on this.

Thanks for Praneeth (below) for his idea, and I modified my code as to get the above issue resolved:

```
 choices = c("ALL", unique(data_set()$variable))
```

and

```
 updateSelectInput(session,"Var1", label = "Select ID", choices = choices, selected=choices[1])
```

Which solved the issue.

But I am getting values in drop down as `"ALL, 1,2,3,4,..."` instead of expected values `"ALL, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3..."`

Any idea why this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI Script would look like this:

```
# SelectInput Query

selectInput(inputId = "S1",label = "Select one of the choices",
               choices = c("All",unique(dataframe()$column)))
```

Here the first value of selectInput being "All" will be selected by default. The choices are All and the unique values of whatever column you need in your dataframe.

Comment: I was wondering if it is part of `updateSelectInput` or `selectInput`?? because, I guess, reactive input will not have ALL as per your suggestion.

Comment: Instead I used `choices = c("ALL", unique(data_set()$variable))` and `updateSelectInput(session,"Var1", label = "Select ID", choices = choices, selected=choices[1])` which solved the issue. but I am getting values in drop down as ALL, 1,2,3,4,... instead of ALL, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3... any idea why??

Comment: Try this on the server side: `updateSelectInput(session, "Var1", selected = "All" )`

Comment: I modified the code and it worked. `choices = c("ALL", unique(data_set()$variable)) ` is what I should have done.